# Посимвольное чтение документа

Tags: java

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться. Нужно прочитать текстовый документ с матрицей символов и числом в конце. Вот пример:

```
o..o......ooooo..oo..
....................o
.o.....oooo..oo..o...
54
```

Матрицу символов, соответственно, нужно записать в двумерную матрицу или список, а символы, к примеру, будут true(o)-false(.), либо байтовские 0(.)-1(o), либо enum, не суть. Число в конце нужно записать в переменную.

Смог вычислить только размер матрицы, ширину и высоту:

```
private int width = 0;
private int height = 0;

public void read(){

    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new     FileReader("D:\\life\\test.txt")))
        {
            String value;
            while ((value = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (width == 0) {
                    width = value.length();
                }
                height++;
            }

            System.out.println("Ширина:" + width + " Высота:" + (height-1));

        }
    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Пробовал метод read(), но он перебирает сразу все символы до конца файла. 
Посоветуйте, как сделать?

Comment: На C#:

    File.ReadLines(filename).Select(s => s.Select(c => c == '.'))

---
Ах да, там ещё одна строка. Тогда так:

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    var matrix = lines.Take(lines.Count - 1)Select(s => s.Select(c => c == '.'));
    var num = int.Parse(lines.Skip(lines.Count - 1).Single());

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, посмотрев их, я сделал следующее:

                String currentLine;
                int row = 0;
                while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                    currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();

                    if (row < (height-1)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                            cells[row][i] = currentLine.charAt(i);
                        }
                    } else {
                        generation = Integer.parseInt(currentLine);
                    }

                    row++;
                }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так:

```
public class ReadMatrix
{
    private int number;
    private boolean [][] matrix;

    public ReadMatrix ( int number, boolean [][] matrix )
    {
        setNumber ( number );
        setMatrix ( matrix );
    }

    public boolean [][] getMatrix () {
        return matrix ;
    }

    public void setMatrix ( boolean [][] matrix ) {
        this.matrix = matrix ;
    }

    public int getNumber () {
        return number ;
    }

    public void setNumber ( int number ) {
        this.number = number ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return toString(matrix) + "\n" + number;
    }

    private String toString ( boolean [][] matrix )
    {
        // or new StringBuilder (matrix.length * matrix [0].length)
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder () ;
        String [] lines = new String [matrix.length] ; 
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < lines.length ; i++ ) {
            if (i != 0) {
                result.append ( "\n" );
            }
            result.append ( toString(matrix[i]) );
        }
        return result.toString () ;
    }

    private String toString ( boolean [] bs )
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder (bs.length) ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < bs.length ; i++ ) {
            result.append ( bs [i] ? 'o' : '.' ) ;
        }
        return result.toString ();
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args ) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // ReadMatrix matrix = getInstance ( System.in) ;
        ReadMatrix matrix = getInstance ( new FileInputStream ( "C:/test.txt" ) ) ;

        System.out.println (matrix) ;
    }

    public static ReadMatrix getInstance(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        // read file
        String[] lines = readFile(inputStream);

        // parse input
        int number = Integer.parseInt ( lines [lines.length - 1] ) ;

        boolean [][] matrix = null;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < lines.length - 1 ; i++ )
        {
            boolean [] tmp = parseLine(lines[i]);
            if (i == 0) {
                matrix = new boolean [lines.length][tmp.length];
            }
            matrix[i] = tmp;
        }

        return new ReadMatrix (number, matrix);
    }

    private static String [] readFile ( InputStream inputStream )
    {
        List<String> result = new LinkedList < String > ();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( inputStream );
        while (scanner.hasNextLine ()) {
            result.add ( scanner.nextLine ().trim () );
        }

        return result.toArray ( new String [result.size ()] ) ;
    }

    private static boolean [] parseLine ( String line )
    {
        char [] chars = line.toCharArray () ;
        boolean [] result = new boolean [chars.length];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < result.length ; i++ ) {
            result[i] = (chars[i] == 'o'); 
        }
        return result ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, что получилось у меня. Данные берутся с stdin.

Ещё бы кто-нибудь сказал, как в java описать тип массива массивов boolean, можно было бы проще написать. Это выше моего понимания этого чуда конца прошлого века. Язык, конечно, не для слабонервных. Страшноватый.

Да, возражения типа ArrayList<boolean []> не надо было преобразовывать в массив -- не принимаются. Просто хотелось посмотреть, что же получится.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
class RPC {
  public static void main (String args []) {
    int width=0, height=0;
    ArrayList<boolean []> matrix = new ArrayList<boolean []> ();
    int number = 0;
    boolean finish = false;

    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String value;
        while ((value = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(finish) {
                System.out.println("Непонятный хвост " + value);
                return;
            }
            value = value.trim();
            if(value.charAt(0) == 'o' || value.charAt(0) == '.') {
                if (width == 0) {
                    width = value.length();
                }
                boolean [] tmp = new boolean [width];
                for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
                    tmp[i] = value.charAt(i) == 'o';
                matrix.add((boolean [])tmp.clone());
                height++;
            }
            else {
                finish = true;
                number = Integer.parseInt(value);
            }
        }
        Object [] matrix_ = matrix.toArray();
        System.out.println("Ширина:" + width + " Высота:" + height);
        for(int h=0; h < height; h++) {
            boolean [] matrixLine = (boolean []) matrix_ [h];
            for(int w=0; w < width; w++) 
                System.out.print((matrixLine[w] ? 't' : 'f') + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Число =" + number);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```